# Basic jdbc authentication, authorization not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am novice in spring security. Just added simple basic authentication to my project  using jdbcauthenticationmanager and it is not working.

**SpringSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource ds;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder getEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(ds).usersByUsernameQuery("select * from users where username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from roles where username = ?")
                .passwordEncoder(getEncoder());
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Spring Security 4 automatically prefixes any role with ROLE_.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER").anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

    }

}
```

**Data in table:**

```
insert into users ( username, password)
values ( 'payal', '$2a$12$YcoYj8Si2mbx.gYTLWwPeu51cfI2bTJlWBnnpaI2uYitfQtKzjPxm');

insert into users ( username, password)
values ( 'admin', '$2a$12$vhk1ELFdkwuvtAb8HrnUzOHEGJsnqX5ZX.C3TV3Q4Vuu9dsDcRH8e');

insert into roles ( username, authority)
values (  'payal', 'ROLE_USER');

insert into roles ( username, authority)
values ( 'admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

The entire code can be found at https://github.com/payalbnsl/SpringMvcSecurity_err

This is using in-memory database with db scripts, so can just run without any extra set-up needed.

It will be of great help if someone can point out why it is not authenticating successfully. **Every username, password, it is saying 401, not authorized**

However it works if i change it to inMemoryAuthentication, hardcoding the username, password.

```
@Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("payal").password("$2a$12$YcoYj8Si2mbx.gYTLWwPeu51cfI2bTJlWBnnpaI2uYitfQtKzjPxm").roles("USER");
        }
```

Comment: I tried in database setting authority to be ROLE_USER, USER and user. None worked. Not sure what exactly is the problem

Comment: `select * from users where username = ` could work or not, depending on your database. Don't use wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked if changed

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(ds).usersByUsernameQuery("select * from users where username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from roles where username = ?")
                .passwordEncoder(getEncoder());
        ;
```

to

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(ds).usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 'true' as enabled from users where username = ?")
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from roles where username = ?")
                    .passwordEncoder(getEncoder());
            ;
```

Adding "'true' as enabled" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store encrypted password using the default method, bcrypt, not plaintext.

Use this to encrypt your passwords and store the encrypted format

```
System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("payal123"));
System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("admin"));
// . . .
```

Comment: Even after adding encoder it does not work! I am using spring 5